# ¿Cómo generar un mensaje una vez finalizado un formulario de Google?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

Tengo un formulario de Google de este estilo:

Entiendo mejor algo

a) si lo practico.

b) si pienso en ello.

Me considero

a) realista.

b) innovador.

Cuando pienso acerca de lo que hice ayer, es más probable que lo haga sobre la base de

a) una imagen.

b) palabras.

Las respuestas son casillas de verificación y son obligatorias y solo se acepta una sola. Lo que quiero hacer es dependiendo la cantidad de respuestas A o B, mostrar por pantalla un mensaje.

Ej:

```
if(cantidadRespuestasA <= 9){    
    System.out.println("EL tipo de aprendizaje que usted tiene es:-----");    
}
```

Lo mismo para las respuestas B

Sería un mensaje tipo diálogo, cuando la persona finaliza el formulario, dependiendo la cantidad de respuestas de tipo A o B, mostrarle un mensaje. La encuesta es sobre tipos de aprendizaje, entonces dependiendo que opciones fueron elegidas, esa persona tiene un tipo de aprendizaje y eso es lo que quiero mostrarle.

¿Cómo lo podría hacer con Google Apps Script?

Comment: ¿Podrías  [editar la pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/105047/edit) y colocar el código de tu formulario por favor? No es necesario que compartas información confidencial.

Comment: ¿Te refieres a un mensaje tipo diálogo para quien envía la respuesta, a un mensaje en el log/consola, un correo electrónico o de otro tipo?

Comment: Rubén: Claro seria un mensaje tipo dialogo, cuando la persona finaliza el formulario, dependiendo la cantidad de respuestas de tipo A o B, mostrarle un mensaje. La encuesta es sobre tipos de aprendizaje, entonces dependiendo que opciones fueron elegidas, esa persona tiene un tipo de aprendizaje y eso es lo que quiero mostrarle.

Comment: Te sugiero usar @ como prefijo de los nombres de usuario ya que esto disparará una notificación. En este caso no es necesario mencionarte con el @ porque tu eres la autora de la publicación. Más detalles en [¿Cómo funcionan las @respuestas en los comentarios?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1358/65)

Comment: Con respecto a los detalles adicionales, usualmente lo mejor [edit] la pregunta para incluir estos pues hacen la pregunta más clara o específica.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Apps Script se puede utilizar para agregar funcionalidad al editor de los formularios, modificar los formularios, crear y enviar respuestas y realizar algunas acciones cuando los formularios han sido enviados pero no para crear diálogos para los que envían respuestas.

Una alternativa sería que utilices el [HTML Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/) de Google Apps Script para crear tu propio formulario HTML y mediante código del lado del cliente usando HTML/CSS/JavaScript agregues el mensaje.

Comment: Muchas gracias Ruben!